# Using location.reload() in ajax doesn't reload the page at first submit (ASP.Net MVC)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller, reload

When I click the button that calls the `JavaScript`, it executes the script which calls the `controller` that inserts the record using `Entity Framework`. But it **doesn't always** reload the page even when I have the `location.reload()`.

What happens is that it successfully submits the record but doesn't reflect in the grid (the list of records), when I submit another record again the first and 2nd inserted record will now show up. Am I doing something wrong with how I'm handling this?

PS, can someone also review my codes as I'm still quite new to web and MVC. Another question of mine is that my form is set like this: `@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "CableSystemType", FormMethod.Get))` but my submit button is declared `POST` in `formmethod`, I'm just wondering if this is good practice and if this has a bearing to my issue.

View

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" formmethod="post" onclick="return SaveUser();" />
```

Javascript

```
function SaveUser() {
    debugger;
    var json = {
        usrId: $('#usrId').val(),
        usrDesc: $('#usrDesc').val(),
        usrStatus: $('input[name=usrStatus]:checked').val()
    };
    var chckUsr = document.getElementById("usrDesc").value;
    var chckStat = document.querySelector('input[name="usrStatus"]:checked').value;

    if (chckUsr === "") {
        alert("Description is required.");
        return false;
    }
    if (chckStat === "") {
        alert("Status is required.");
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/User/Save_User',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(json),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null && response.success) {
                //User is unique
                alert(response.responseText);
            } else {
                //User already exists
                alert("response.responseText);
            }
            //When I put alert in this area it shows up, but page doesn't refresh. I use Chrome
            location.reload();
        },
    });

};
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult Save_User(UserViewModel model)
{
    string _message = string.Empty;

    using (var _odb = new DBEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            if (_odb.USR_MSTR.Any(o => o.USR_DESC == model.usrDesc))
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "User already exists." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else {
                USR_MSTR usr_master = new USR_MSTR();
                string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                usr_master.USR_ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Remove(5);
                usr_master.USR_DESC = model.usrDesc;
                usr_master.CREA_DT = DateTime.Now;

                if (model.usrStatus == "Active")
                {
                    usr_master.INACTV_DT = null;
                }
                else if (model.usrStatus == "Inactive")
                {
                    usr_master.INACTV_DT = DateTime.Now;
                }

                _odb.USR_MSTR.Add(usr_master);
                _odb.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "User sucessfully saved." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _message = "An error occured.";
            _message = ex.InnerException.Message;
        }
    }
    return Json(true);
}
```

Comment: Why in the world are you using ajax if you want to refresh the page (its pointless). Either do a normal submit and redirect, or just update the relevant part of the DOM in the success callback

Comment: I suggest you to use partial view for both submission form & grid containing list of records, then your ajax callback should return the grid partial view when POST-ing form data, thus you don't need to refresh entire page when submitting user records.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm sorry this is the code setup (View > JS > Controller) I was taught when I came in my project, which is still in the development stage. I just added the refresh part just to force the page to show the recently added record. Thanks for the tip, I'll do some research on that.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I've seen partial view many times but haven't had checked on it thoroughly. Looks like I'm gonna be needing this with my current issue. I'm gonna look for tutorials now, thanks man!